# Will mouse enter work on invisible componenets?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jlabel, mouselistener

This is going to be on a form used as a sort of search function. It will be an array of `JLabel`s, with things like first names, last name etc.

The user will add names to the list one by one for submission to a database. I will use a prepared batch statement with some `.getText()`'s to get my text. It may sound complicated but it seems to be working.

What if the user is looking and wants to remove a name?

I'm thinking a `JLabel` that is hidden (`setVisible(false)`) until `MouseEnter`. Using the `mouseClicked` action to call a method to do the dirty work.

My question is, if I add a `JLabel` to a `JPanel`, and set it's visible property to false, is it still actually there, and can I set it visible with a `mouseEnter` action?

Comment: Short answer, no.  To my mind, you either what to use `JCheckBox`s or maybe even a `JList` with multi selection enabled (but I refer the check boxes, but that's me)

Comment: Can't you just override the JLabel's paintComponent() method to call super if mouse is over only?